# Android NoSuchMethodError getTxPower

Tags: android, nosuchmethoderror

```
 scanResult.getTxPower()
```

This is throwing `NoSuchMethodError` in Bluetooth LE scanning. It seems that this is added to API level 26 and I'm running the code on API level 24 or 23, but I did not get any warning or errors while compiling or in the code editor anyway

Is there any way to get `TXpower` in API 21 or 23 or 24. my goal is to calc the distance based on the `getRssi` and get TxPower, so if there's any other way to find distance without the TXPower or anyway else that would help. That's the code I'm using to calc the distance

```
   double getDistance(int rssi, double txPower) {
                /*
                 * RSSI = TxPower - 10 * n * lg(d)
                 * n = 2 (in free space)
                 *
                 * d = 10 ^ ((TxPower - RSSI) / (10 * n))
                 */

        return Math.pow(10d, (txPower - rssi) / (10 * 2));
    }
```